# How to retrieve the data of <s:radio> within <s:iterator> tag into Struts2's action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I need to do something in webpage like this :
a bunch of rows that display questions and choices , the choices are made up of radio buttions.
I don't konw how to get these radio button's data into my java code.
 This is my jsp code:

```
<s:iterator value="questionsList" status="status" var="questionsList">
    <tr>
        <td><s:property value="title"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>    
         <td>
             <s:radio list="{'A','B','C','D'}" name="[%{#status.index}]answer" theme="simple"/>
         </td>
     </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

I've tried

```
private List answer = new ArrayList();
answer = (List)request.getAttribute("[%{#status.index}]answer");
```

but it doesn't work.
If you have other means to do this please tell me, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide indexed property names for the lists you want to get in Java

```
<s:iterator value="questionsList" status="status">
    <tr>
        <td><s:property value="title"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>    
         <td>
             <s:radio list="{'A','B','C','D'}" name="questionsList[%{#status.index}].answer" theme="simple"/>
         </td>
     </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Voila! Your question list will be populated with indexes provided by `status.index` variable.

Comment: @user3306123 Welcome to StackOverflow! If this answer helped you to solve problem you should mark it as accepted. See [how to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).